# LeNet5 inference based on quantize TFLite model. How to downscale int32 to int8 with the M parameter?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, inference, quantization

I trained a LeNet5 CNN with Keras/TensorFlow. I used TensorFlow Lite to quantized FP32 weights and activations to INT8. I extracted and visualized weights, biases, scales en zero-points thanks to Netron.

I needed to design LeNet5 CNN in C langage. In FP32 format, my model inference works fine. However, I don't understand some point to do the inference with the INT8 format.

From the paper : "Quantization and Training of Neural Networks for Efficient Integer-Arithmetic-Only Inference" : https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.05877 , authors detailed the following workflow to do an inference with a quantize INT8 convolution :
[convolution INT8 inference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vJq1.png)
After the convolution step between the input and the weights, then adding the bias, authors precise that the downscale from INT32 to INT8 is done thanks to the M constant define by M = (S1*S2)/S3.

S1 is the scale of the input. And for me, S2 is the scale of the weights and S3 is the scale of the output.

However in Netron, for the conv2d weights I can not view the scale involved :
[conv2d filters in Netron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtDXv.png)

But I can view the scale for Fully Connected operations :
[dense weights in Netron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkwPr.png)

My question is : what is S2 for the convolution ? Is it a problem of Netron visualization or do I misunderstood the M downsampling factor for the convolution process ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Netron doesnt support the tflite per-channel quantization parameters.

There is a scale for each output channel. Use the tflite interpreter to inspect these.

```
i = tf.lite.Interpreter('/path/to/my_model.tflite')
[y['quantization_parameters'] for y in i.get_tensor_details() \
  if y['name'] == 'sequential/conv2d_1/Conv2D']
```